# Nito.AsyncEx + .Net-4.0 = 'AsyncContext' does not exist in the namespace 'Nito.AsyncEx'

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I need to run Nito.AsyncEx with library targeting .Net-4.0. I'm trying the following simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TempNet40
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
        }

        static async void MainAsync(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

While the above compiles when my lib targets .Net-4.5 or higher - it fails for .Net-4.0 with error:

> The type or namespace name 'AsyncContext' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Nito.AsyncEx' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Nito.AsyncEx (as well as its .Net-4.0 dependency: Microsoft.Bcl.Async) was installed using NuGet - I guess for .Net-4.0, I need to reference another library... does anybody know which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you install it with NuGet, this will also help you manage your dependencies.

Just right-click on your project and select *manage NuGet packages*

If you would like to look up the dependencies on your own, you can check on the NuGet homepage: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx

I managed to reproduce your problem. I solved it with upgrading `Microsoft.Bcl` to Version `1.1.10`

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I did - First I installed packages on solution level using the "Manage NuGet packages for solution" option. Then I tried installing packages directly for the project using "Manage NuGet packages for project" - both gave me the same error during compilation. In both cases, I only installed Nito.AsyncEx - , NuGet marked the dependencies automatically.

Comment: I managed to compile your example with upgrading to Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10

Comment: Yep, that did it - thank you. I didn't try updating, because I thought NuGet always installs latest packages, interesting to find out it doesn't...